# Can't start Testcontainers Docker in Mac M1

Tags: docker, apple-m1, testcontainers

I have a M1 Pro chip and I'm trying to run some integration tests via Testcontainers.

For this, I've installed Docker desktop, and every time I try to run the test containers container, almost instantly I receive the message `panic: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

I have enabled in docker settings the `Allow the default Docker socket to be used` feature, which creates the `/var/run/docker.sock` file. I have rebooted my machine several times but it still doesn't work. Is there any solution to this?

Docker version: 4.21.1

Test containers image: ryuk:0.4.0

MacOS Ventura 13.4.1 under M1 Pro

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, you typically install Docker using Docker Desktop (if it's your case). Ensure that Docker Desktop is running. If you forget to launch it, you might encounter the following error:

```
➜  ~ docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Comment: As I said, I've installed Docker via Docker Desktop. In the UI, while launching the testcontainers container, I get the mentioned error.